# Powershell - last two characters in the text line

Tags: powershell

I would appreciate if someone point me in a right direction.

Task(s) ----------

1. Split the string and assign folder path (note blank spaces in the path) to different variables.

OR

2. Get lines from text file and extract last 2 characters ignoring blank spaces between folder path and assigned drive letter.

Example of a text file ----------

\FileServer\movetest\somefiles          Z:
\FileServer\mogul MOVE OUT\anotherfiles Y:

Attempt to code ----------
1)

```
 $getDriveLines = gc -Path $inputFile    

foreach( $_ in $getDriveLines)                                                                    { 
   [stringsplitoptions]$option = "removeEmptyEntries" $oldFILEPath = $_.split(" ",$option)[0]
   Write-Host ("Old FS path is ") $oldFILEPath

   $constantFILEDriveLetter = $_.split(" ",$option)[1]
   Write-Host ("Constant FS Letter is ") $constantFILEDriveLetter }
```

Problem ---------- please note that it splits folder path (3rd line) and shows in last line of output part of a  "folder path" and not the drive letter.

```
      Old FS path is  \\FileServer\\movetest\\somefiles
```

Constant FS Letter is  Z:
Old FS path is  \FileServer\mogul
Constant FS Letter is  MOVE

)

$getDriveLines = gc -Path $inputFile

```
  foreach( $Line in $getDriveLines)
```

{

$value = $Line.Substring($Line.Length - 2)

```
 }
```

Problem ---------- it displays the following, please NOTE that there is no value displayed for "Z:" second line

```
   \\\\FileServer\\movetest\\somefiles          Z:  
     The value is -  
   \\\\FileServer\\mogul MOVE OUT\\anotherfiles Y:
```

The value is -  Y:

Is it overwritten ?  What this code is missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- There is no easy solution with the `.Split()` .NET *method*, which operates on *literal* separator strings, but concise solutions are possible with the *regex*-based `-split` *operator* - see below.
- Your `.Substring()` approach - `$value = $Line.Substring($Line.Length - 2)` to get the drive spec. - was likely only hampered by *trailing spaces* in the first line of your input file, which you could easily fix as follows:

  ```
  $getDriveLines = (gc -Path $inputFile).Trim()
  ```

---

In *PowerShell (Core) 7+* there is a straightforward solution, using the [`-split` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) with a *negative* token count, specifically `-2`:

```
(Get-Content $inputFile).Trim() | ForEach-Object {
  $path, $drive = $_ -split ' +', -2
  # Sample output
  [pscustomobject] @{
    Path = $path
    Drive = $drive
  }
}
```

- [Regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) `' +'` matches one or more (`+`) spaces (`' '`).
- `-2` tells `-split` to return *at most 2* tokens *from the end*, due to the number being negative. This causes the splitting to effectively be performed only at the *last* run of spaces in the input string, so that the path preceding the drive spec. at the end is preserved as-is, even if it contains spaces too.

Output:

```
Path                                       Drive
----                                       -----
\\FileServer\\movetest\\somefiles          Z:
\\FileServer\\mogul MOVE OUT\\anotherfiles Y:
```

---

In *Windows PowerShell*, where negative token counts aren't supported, a concise solution is a bit more complex:

```
(Get-Content $inputFile).Trim() | ForEach-Object {
  $path, $drive = $_ -split ' +(?=[a-z]:$)'
  # Sample output
  [pscustomobject] @{
    Path = $path
    Drive = $drive
  }
}
```

- Here too it is ensured that the input string is only split by the *last* run of spaces, by using a (positive) *look-ahead assertion* (`(?=...)`) that only matches a run of spaces  (`' +'`) if it is followed by subexpression that matches a drive spec. (`[a-z]:`) at the end of the string (`$`).

Answer (score 0):

Your post was hard to read but reading your headline i might have a script that will help you

```
foreach ( $line in (Get-Content -Path $inputFile)) { 
   $oldFILEPath = $line.Substring(0,$line.length -3)
   $constantFILEDriveLetter = $line.Substring($line.length -2, 2)

   Write-Output "Old FS path is `"$oldFILEPath`""
   Write-Output "Constant FS letter is $constantFILEDriveLetter`r`n"
}
```

Result looks like

```
Old FS path is "\FileServer\movetest\somefiles"
Constant FS letter is Z:

Old FS path is "\FileServer\mogul MOVE OUT\anotherfiles"
Constant FS letter is Y:
```

Answer (score 0):

My apologies to "An-dir"  and "mklement0"  for a messy post.  But yes the problem was with notorious trailing blank spaces.  I appreciate your time and efforts to check my post and give me your ideas.